# Random errors in capybara, which seem to stem from capybara not being able to click a link that is obviously there, and clickable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

It seems that every so often, randomly, capybara has trouble clicking a link in my rails app, and I can't figure out why. I'll look at the screenshot provided and from what it looks like, the link is there, and capybara should be able to click it, but at random times it fails to do so.

I've noticed that in general, when I click on links sometimes there's no effect. I wonder if this has something to do with turbolinks. I don't know if this actually has anything to do with the problem, as this doesn't seem to be something I can easily reproduce, just a hunch.

I have no idea what the issue is, thus here I am asking for help :)

EDIT: I've thrown in some `visit current_path` statements just before the problem areas... I figure maybe a 'refresh' might help capybara in order to click the links? I've read that some methods will "wait" for an element to appear on the page, and other methods won't, so I wonder if that has something to do with it.

The issue is literally that I'm calling `click_link "Link Text"` and the screenshot shows that the link is there... I'm not sure what the problem could be.

Comment: You'll need to provide an example of your test and exact error message you get for anyone to give you useful feedback.  Also helpful would be the exact HTML of the element Capybara is saying doesn't exist so we can verify it would actually match what Capybara is looking for.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I have a feeling this is a common issue, and that someone who understands the issue will comment if they're inclined to. It's literally just "could not click on link" even though the link is there in the screenshot. Like it's not much more complicated than that. It's sporadic, so I can't just reproduce it on command, otherwise I would include the error. I've added some "visit current_path" statements to "refresh" and it seems that may have solved the issue, but I'd like to see if someone who has experience with this same issue might be able weigh in.

Comment: As the person who actually writes Capybara I've asked you for what's necessary to debug your issue - if you don't feel like providing that info that's your prerogative.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole again, it's not something I can reproduce on command, otherwise I'd give you an error message. I believe this is a situation where you either know the answer or you don't.